# Can I Switch Bodyguard

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have two followers that can act as a bodyguard. The follower that I want to be my bodyguard is on a mission, so I want to assign the other one until they have finished.

Once I assign one of my followers as a bodyguard can I change the bodyguard to another follower later on?

I found the following bodyguard guide: [Guide to the Garrison Barracks](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=2726/guide-to-the-garrison-barracks), it mentions that when a bodyguard dies you must go back to the garrison to get them, but it doesn't seem to indicate that it's possible to change bodyguards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your bodyguard at any time (provided the bodyguard you wish to switch to is not on a mission or working in another building) by assigning them to your Barracks, in the same way you did the first time.